# How to detect connections - Firefox

Tags: firefox

I want to block some connections make by **Firefox itself** or its **extensions** using windows hosts file.

How can i read/detect to which Domains or IPs Firefox make connections?

is there any extension to show the connections?

Comment: You can get connection log from Developer mode in Firefox or with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lightbeam extension for Firefox *may* do what you need it to.  Take a look at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/lightbeam/

Failing this, you can use Firefox developer tools and look at the network tab to see where you are being connected to.

A packet capture tool may be another way to go - take a look at Wireshark.

There is also free proxy software on the net which you can install to effectively "sniff" and copy all web traffic leaving and arriving at your PC so you can audit and block it where necessary.  For a good recommendation of one to use - take a look at the software recs stack exchange.